# What is the original song for The Wiggles' "New South Wales Blues song"?

Tags: identify-this-song, cover

I heard an old tune on the radio but can't remember what it is, it's driving me crazy. I think it's an 80's ska song but not 100% sure.

It is the original song to this one covered by the Wiggles, the [*New South Wales Blues song*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6cZ6Yx2bz5Y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The song you are thinking of is "Tom Hark" by The Piranhas from 1980. Which is itself a cover of an original song from 1958 by Jack Lerole, according to Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks mate.  You've put me out my misery lol